# How to display percentage above grouped bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

The following are the pandas dataframe and the bar chart generated from it:

```
colors_list = ['#5cb85c','#5bc0de','#d9534f']
result.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,4),width = 0.8,color = colors_list,edgecolor=None)
plt.legend(labels=result.columns,fontsize= 14)
plt.title("Percentage of Respondents' Interest in Data Science Areas",fontsize= 16)

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
plt.yticks([])
```

[image: Dataframe]
[image: Bar Chart]

I need to display the percentages of each interest category for the respective subject above their corresponding bar. I can create a list with the percentages, but I don't understand how to add it on top of the corresponding bar.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try adding the following `for` loop to your code:

```
ax = result.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,4), width=0.8, color=colors_list, edgecolor=None)

for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate(f'{height}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
```

---

#### Explanation

In general, you use [`Axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) to add annotations to your plots.
This method takes the `text` value of the annotation and the `xy` coords on which to place the annotation.

In a barplot, each "bar" is represented by a [`patch.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) and each of these rectangles has the attributes `width`, `height` and the `xy` coords of the lower left corner of the rectangle, all of which can be obtained with the methods `patch.get_width`, `patch.get_height` and `patch.get_xy` respectively.

Putting this all together, the solution is to loop through each patch in your `Axes`, and set the annotation text to be the `height` of that patch, with an appropriate `xy` position that's just above the centre of the patch - calculated from it's height, width and xy coords.

---

For your specific need to annotate with the percentages, I would first normalize your `DataFrame` and plot that instead.

```
colors_list = ['#5cb85c','#5bc0de','#d9534f']

# Normalize result
result_pct = result.div(result.sum(1), axis=0)

ax = result_pct.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,4),width = 0.8,color = colors_list,edgecolor=None)
plt.legend(labels=result.columns,fontsize= 14)
plt.title("Percentage of Respondents' Interest in Data Science Areas",fontsize= 16)

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
plt.yticks([])

# Add this loop to add the annotations
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate(f'{height:.0%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

- From `matplotlib 3.4.2`, use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)
- Modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493864/7758804), which has a different calculation, and a different label format.
- Plot the DataFrame directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and `kind='bar'`
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for more documentation and examples using the `.bar_label` method.
- Adjust which axis is used in `.div` and `.sum` to determine the percent relative to the columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

file="https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DV0101EN/labs/coursera/Topic_Survey_Assignment.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)

df.sort_values(by=['Very interested'], axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)

# calculate the percent relative to the index
df_percent = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round(1)

# display(df_percent)
                            Very interested  Somewhat interested  Not interested
Data Analysis / Statistics             77.0                 20.3             2.7
Machine Learning                       74.7                 21.9             3.4
Data Visualization                     61.6                 33.7             4.7
Big Data (Spark / Hadoop)              60.9                 33.3             5.8
Deep Learning                          58.2                 35.5             6.3
Data Journalism                        20.2                 51.0            28.8

# set the colors
colors = ['#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#d9534f']

# plot with annotations is probably easier
p1 = df_percent.plot(kind='bar', color=colors, figsize=(20, 8), rot=0, ylabel='Percentage', title="The percentage of the respondents' interest in the different data science Area")

for p in p1.containers:
    p1.bar_label(p, fmt='%.1f%%', label_type='edge')
```

[image]