# Jupyter noterbook How to show percentage on bar graph for this code?

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to show the percentage on the bar graph from the code below, how do I do it?

```
results = pd.Series([accu_dt , accu_svm, accu_rf, accu_lg, accu_knn, accu_nb  ])
names = ['Decision Tree','SVm','Random Forest','Logistic Regression','KNN','Naive Bayes']
ax = results.plot(kind = 'bar',figsize=(13,7),color=['black','gray','brown','blue','pink','green'])
ax.set_title('Comparision of Models',fontsize=15)
ax.set_yticks([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
ax.set_xticklabels(names ,fontsize=15,rotation = 45)
ax.set_xlabel("Models",fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("Accuracy",fontsize=15)
```

Comment: From "on the bar graph" you mean that you want the value of each bar above?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was just wanted percentage on top of the bar graph.

Comment: It's much better to use official tools. You can use `bar_label`. Read [official doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html) for further information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

Answer (score 1):

Is this your expected output?

[image: Sample Plot]

If so, credit to [Chris Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082020/12619695) for his answer.

I predefined the values for `accu_dt , accu_svm, accu_rf, accu_lg, accu_knn, accu_nb` as such:

```
accu_dt   = [0.90,0.92,0.91,0.95,0.99,0.95,0.90]
accu_svm  = [0.89,0.92,0.95,0.98,0.97,0.89,0.95]
accu_rf   = [0.98,0.99,0.97,0.96,0.98,0.99,0.95]
accu_lg   = [0.79,0.77,0.90,0.85,0.83,0.80,0.78]
accu_knn  = [0.85,0.85,0.84,0.89,0.83,0.81,0.80]
accu_nb   = [0.85,0.84,0.83,0.81,0.85,0.85,0.85]
```

I didn't change much of your code except the `width = 0.7` and the  `figsize=(30,7)` to make the numbers more readable. Noticed that I added loop at the bottom of your code

```
ax = results.plot(kind = 'bar',figsize=(30,7),color=['black','gray','brown','blue','pink','green'],width = 0.7)
ax.set_title('Comparision of Models',fontsize=15)
ax.set_yticks([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
ax.set_xticklabels(names ,fontsize=15,rotation = 45)
ax.set_xlabel("Models",fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("Accuracy",fontsize=15)

# Newly Added Loop
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate(f'{height:.0%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
```

Basically what the code does in simple term:

1. Getting the heights, width and (x,y) coordinate of the bars
2. Set the annotation at designated (x,y) coordinate
3. Set the VALUE of the annotation equals the height of the bar (the `'.0%'` means percentage with zero decimal place)

Comment: Thank you this solves my query. Very helpful. Cheers you to.